# How to compare ENUMS in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, if-statement, enums

I've stored some Enums and I'd like to compare them in my frontend.

Here are my Enums:

```
src/shared/models/report/data-type.enum.ts
export enum DataType {
  DASHBOARD = 'DASHBOARD',
  REPORT = 'REPORT',
  APP = 'APP',
}
```

In my component, I'd like to compare if it's an `APP` or some other value. If it's an `APP` Enum, I'd like to show an other button in my frontend.

```
src/shared/components/report-modal/report-modal.component.ts

readonly isApplication = this.DataType.APP === true
```

Here is the code of the html component:

```
src/shared/components/report-modal/report-modal.component.html
      <div *ngIf="!hasNoAccess && isApplication" >
        <a class="button"
           [class.button--primary]="hasAccess"
           [class.button--secondary]="!hasAccess"
           [attr.href]="report.link"
           aria-describedby="access-btn-hint"
           target="_blank">{{'REPORT.GO_TO_APP'|translate}}</a>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="!hasNoAccess && !isApplication" >
        <a class="button"
           [class.button--primary]="hasAccess"
           [class.button--secondary]="!hasAccess"
           [attr.href]="report.link"
           aria-describedby="access-btn-hint"
           target="_blank">{{'REPORT.GO_TO_REPORT'|translate}}</a>
      </div>
```

How can I make that work? THX

Comment: Have you tried `this.DataType === DataType.APP` ?

Comment: Yes, then I get always false

Comment: So what is the value of `this.DataType`?

Comment: It's `undefined`.

Comment: Well there you go, `undefined` will never be equal to `DataType.App`. Go and figure out why it is `undefined` and once you solve that try again.

Comment: But how can I get there the right value?

Comment: `But how can I get there the right value?` ← I do not know because there is insufficient information in your question to answer that. You never stated how this value should be filled, from where, or showed any additional component related code. Apparently you want it assigned from somewhere/something but without any context the only person that can answer this is you.